# Refresh div content after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've just send my form by POST in django (saving some data), and after that saving, I want to refresh the list within the modal, but without refreshing the whole page. Do I have to specify the whole path to the modal etc. ? Is there a jQuery command like F5 button but not for the whole page, only a div?

My code I'm working with:

```
$(function(){
  $('#js-submit-create-adres').on('click', function (e) {
      var form = $('#create-adres');
      var _czy = '';
      if ($('#id_czy_domyslny option:selected').text() == 'Tak') {
          _czy = 'True';
      } else  {
          _czy = 'False';
      }
      $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('data-url'),
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
              ulica: $('#id_ulica').val(),
              kod_pocztowy: $('#id_kod_pocztowy').val(),
              miasto: $('#id_miasto').val(),
              kontrahent: $('#id_kontrahent').val(),
              czy_domyslny: _czy,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
          },
          success: function(msg){
              if(msg.result == 'done') {
                  if(_czy == 'True'){
                    $('#kontrahent-adres').text(nowy_adres);
                  }
                  alert('saved');
                  $('#id_ulica').val('');
                  $('#id_kod_pocztowy').val('');
                  $('#id_miasto').val('');
                  // HERE I WANT TO RELOAD DIV NAMED '#name'
              }
        }
      })
    })
})
```

Comment: Just append the code returned from your AJAX request to your div. Something like `div.textContent = your_code`

Comment: That means, I have to serialize all the new stuff, send it by ajax, get it by jquery, and add it to the list, which I try to avoid. The new data occurs when I click F5. I don't want to click it.

Comment: No it doesn't, you can render a template in your Django view and return that in the Ajax response, then append it directly.

Comment: i'll share my solution just a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def adres_kontrahent_create(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        nowy_adres = AdresKontrahentForm(request.POST)
        if nowy_adres.is_valid():
            nowy_adres.save()
            rendered = render_to_string('escrm/adresy/kontrahentadres_list_modal.html',
                                        {'object': nowy_adres.cleaned_data.get('kontrahent')})
            data['modal'] = rendered
            data['result'] = 'success'
        else:
            data['result'] = 'failed'
        return JsonResponse(data)
```